# Error al buscar numero de documento en macro excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Tengo una macro de excel cuando le doy clic al botón consultar y modificar datos me trae un formulario donde se puede hacer la búsqueda por nombre y por número de documento la imagen es el inicio de la macro donde se le debe de dar clic al botón para que salga el formulario[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este formulario es donde se hace la búsqueda, cuando se hace la búsqueda por documento del cliente o por número de cliente al darle clic a buscar no funciona he seguido los pasos a pasos pero no logrado dar con el error. 
agradezco a quien me pueda dar la mano o alguna idea de como resolverlo dejo el vínculo del archivo [Macro Excel download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vB_QbRBaExjNsPYxe_uBoUdUgMG0G33B/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Habría que incluirlo en el código del formulario "MODIFICAR_CLIENTE"
pero entiendo, según veo el libro, que **has de utilizar la pestaña "COMBOS"** que está oculta.

**Paso 1:** Desoculta esta pestaña (Click derecho en pestañas / mostrar)

**Paso 2:** Añades al listado de combos los valores que sí existen en la pestaña datos pero que no existen en los combos. 
ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

repetir paso 2 para "MARCA" y "DEPARTAMENTO (PROVINCIA)".

[image: Pestaña combos:]

la idea es que cada valor que exista en estas columnas de la pestaña datos exista también de forma idéntica en la pestaña "COMBOS"

una vez realizado este paso, el formulario buscará el cliente como deseas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero haberte aclarado. ya me cuentas

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono con las indicaciones dadas

Answer (score 0):

no indicas exactamente el error pero supongo que te refieres al error al rellenar el formulario en la consulta.

Este error viene determinado porque intentas seleccionar un valor que no se encuentra en el combobox ni se ha tenido en cuenta este valor en los condicionales programados cuando cambia este combo.

Cuando la macro intenta seleccionar "NIF" en combobox2 (o cualquiera) arroja error porque este valor no se encuentra entre los items del desplebable.

es necesario añadirlo antes al desplegable o a dinámicamente a través del siguiente comando:

```
MODIFICAR_CLIENTE.ComboBox2.AddItem Worksheets("DATOS").Cells(i, 9).Value
```

Una vez añadido la sentencia donde el error salta debería funcionar. 
mismo resultado para cada uno de los combos a los que intentes añadir un valor que no contiene

Comment: JorgeBB muchas gracias, me podrias indicar en qué parte del código se puede agregar  la linea que mencionas.